# Android network errors connecting to an address

Tags: android, sockets

Snippet provided:

```
public void update(){
   try {
        Socket appSoc = new Socket( "XXX.XXX.XXX.X" ,XXXXX);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(appSoc.getInputStream()));
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String message = in.readLine();
            add(message);}

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        add("ERROR" + e);
    }
}
```

`add(String text)` adds text to a textview.

Using the domain name instead of the IP address says that the phone cannot find the domain, is this an android problem, because it runs fine on java on the desktop.

Comment: Did you add the following permission to your manifest: `<uses-permission      android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`?

Comment: Facepalm... man I need to pay more attention

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably missing the Internet persmission in your manifest.  Make sure it is located outside of the application tag, like this:

```
<manifest>
    <application>
     .
     .
     .
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5):

In your androidmanifest.xml, check to see if you have given proper internet permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```